# program runs in netbeans but not in command prompt

Tags: java, jar, netbeans-7, command-prompt, noclassdeffounderror

I have a project running perfectly in netbeans, windows 8, I build the jar file project-> build with dependencies. When I try to run it from command prompt with this command:

```
java -jar OracleBackup.jar
```

it throws this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/datalayer/DB  
at com.mycompany.oraclebackup.App.main<App.java:12>  
caused by: java.lang.classNotFoundException: com.mycompany.datalayer.DB  
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run<unknown source>
```

I have searched a lot, I have made some changes, but it still doesn't work.

more details:

> path:
>   %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin

When I open the .jar file:

> 1) I can see DB.class in com/mycompany/datalayer/DB
>
> 2)Manifest file exists and this is the content:  Manifest-Version: 1.0
>   Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver  Created-By: Apache Maven  Built-By:
>   Moises David  Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_17  Main-Class:
>   com.mycompany.oraclebackup.App

Should I mention my .jar dependencies in here too?

Can someone tell me what the problem is and how I can solve it?

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: how are you exported as a jar ? Are you using Eclipse or is it Maven project?

Comment: I'am using netbean 7.3.1 and maven.  sorry didnt understand "how are you exported as a jar ?". If u mean how I get the jar file.. by project->build with dependencies. created in the target folder.

Comment: If you are using maven then you don't need to export like that.You should run Maven plugin to export as runnable jar. It will also include all the dependent jar files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven This should help you

Comment: Makky, thank you so much!! I finally get it to work! :)